# What is the grammar used for visual studio solution (.sln) files?

Tags: python, visual-studio, parsing

I want to parse visual studio solution files, and project files in Python. The project files are XML files, hence can be easily parsed. The `.sln` files seem to follow a different convention. I couldn't find a library for Python which would help me in parsing the file. 
The only solution I am left with is to create a library myself. For that I need the grammar used by `.sln` file. I can use this grammar to use flex/bison type stuff in Python to parse the file correctly.

This [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx) article sheds some light on its structure but is far from complete.

Comment: [This](http://blog.bfitz.us/?p=955) might be (partly) helpful if you haven't seen it already.

Comment: @Tagc That link is outdated, do you have an update?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20180223060109/http://blog.bfitz.us/?p=955

@SebastianK : I found a version of the link stored on wayback machine.